# Android MediaCodec encoding + camera2 how to create a black screen for pause and resume

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview

I have created a surface with the MediaCodec and added it as a target to the camera2 api. Now I want to sometime pause the MediaCodec encoding and then resume it. What I expect is the encoded video **to become black when I pause** and continue when I resume. Using `MediaCodec.PARAMETER_KEY_SUSPEND` doesn't do the job since the output is a frozen frame, and if the paused happens at the beginning of encoding the time starts when I resume. So I was thinking of feeding the encoder with black image, but how can I draw on the surface? Thanks!

Edit: Here is some of the code I use to make the camera2 work with MediaCodec.

1. I create a simple MediaCodec:

   ```
   try {
       mediaCodec =
           MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mime)
       Logger.d(TAG, "MediaCodec info " + mediaCodec.codecInfo.name)


   } catch (e: IOException) {
       e.printStackTrace()
   }
   mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)

   val inputSurface = mediaCodec.createInputSurface() //<-- this is passed to the camera2
   ```
2. I add the surface to the camera:

   ```
   captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(inputSurface);
   List<Surface> surfaceList = new ArrayList<>();
           surfaceList.add(cameraFrame.getSurface());
           surfaceList.add(inputSurface);

           camera.createCaptureSession(
                   surfaceList,
                   captureSessionObserver,
                   cameraThreadHandler
           );
   ```

And then in a loop I read the mediaCodec output buffers and write them into a muxer.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw a black image on a surfaceView something like this:

```
val surface = getSurfaceFromSomething()
val canvas = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) surface.lockHardwareCanvas()
else surface.lockCanvas(null)
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
```

Or also you can try this MediaCodec feature:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat#KEY_PUSH_BLANK_BUFFERS_ON_STOP

Comment: Tested the KEY_PUSH_BLANK_BUFFERS_ON_STOP - did not work. When do you think is the time to do the surface thing?

Comment: You can try to draw on a surface right after you called some of mediaCodec methods to pause it. If it won't work you can try to detect BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM and draw a black frame right after you got this flag. Also there are a couple of dirty hacks you can just set black background color to the SurfaceView which the surface belong to (surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)) or you can create an ImageView with black background and place it under surfaceView on the screen and hide it when you resume mediaCodec and show it when you pause.

Comment: This sounds like hacks that might work on 1 device but not for others.

Comment: As for the first two things yeah it might take place, but as for the last two ones I would like to note that they will work on all the devices

Comment: I tried the surfaceview.setBackgroundColor and it didn't do anything. the camera2 has list of surface that it write into.

Comment: What I want to acheive is that the recording will be black, not the view.

Comment: Your answer isn't working..

Comment: can you share some code how you create your surface set it to camera 2 api and how you tried to draw a black frame on the surface? And another question why are you using Camera 2 and not CameraX ?

Comment: I will share code, but this is why i use camera2 and not camerax https://stackoverflow.com/a/56303135/588532